# CSS Push table to bottom of page

Tags: html, css

For some reason my (html) is not rendering proprely I have to push table#footer to the bottom. I have situation like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <table id="footer"></table>
    <div id="text"></div>
</div>
```

Is it possible in css to push first child element to the bottom without position absolute?
I need to keep table just after div#text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider flebox and `order` like this:

```css
#container {
  height:80vh;
  border:1px solid;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
#footer {
  order:1;
  margin-top:auto;
  border:1px solid green;
  height:20px;
  width:100%;
}
#text {
  border:1px solid orange;
  height:20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <table id="footer"></table>
    <div id="text"> text</div>
</div>
```